# What does dictionary really store as a value in C#?

Tags: c#, dictionary, reference, reference-type

I'm using a specific datasource from devexpress called VirtualServerMode. It's a read-only datasource by default. To enable ability to edit data I need to pass collection implementing the IList interface.

I use Dictionary to store different collections.

When I create collection in this way:

Using constructor to initialize the dictionary

```csharp
protected AbstractRepository()
{
    _className = typeof(TCardType).Name;
    _acquireList = new Dictionary<string, BindingList<TCardType>>();
    _acquireList[_className] = new BindingList<TCardType>();
}
```

And the property returns the value

```csharp
   public BindingList<TCardType> AcquireList => _acquireList[_className];
```

The Devexpress component does not recognize the collection and edit mode is not enabled.

If I initialize the dictionary in like this

```csharp
public IList GreateAcquireList()
{
    var outcome = new BindingList<TCardType>();
    _acquireList[_className] = outcome;
    return outcome;
}
```

And pass the collection to the datasource

```csharp
private void FileCardDatasource_AcquireInnerList(object sender, VirtualServerModeAcquireInnerListEventArgs e)
{
    e.InnerList = Report.GreateAcquireList();
}
```

The component recognises the collection and edit mode is enabled.

Why does the dictionary not return a reference to the reference type value?

Comment: Set a breakpoint on the code line you think does not work and you will see what the dictionary returns or whether the line is called at all. [Tutorial: Learn to debug C# code using Visual Studio](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/get-started/csharp/tutorial-debugger).

Comment: A dictionary does not duplicate the value.  It only contains a link to the value.  You are creating a duplicate value when you use "new BindingList<TCardType>()"

Comment: I don't see why the dictionary would be relevant to this question. Your first example seem to use a completely different method than the second example, that is probably the reason it works.

Comment: If youre complaining that the component doesn't work when you do `e.InnerList = SOMETHING.AcquireList;` but does work when you do `e.InnerList = Report.GreateAcquireList();` I would start by assessing how the component behaves differently when given a BindingList<T> versus an IList

Comment: @JonasH, the difference between two examples in the method to return the reference to the collection. In the first one I create collection in the constructor and then get it by Key from the Dictionary. In the second one I create collection assign it to the variable and then assign this variable to the Dictionary and return its.

Comment: @HasBeanCounter, Yes, you've got me exactly. But I don't understand why I need to evaluate the behavior of the component, because I can't change it. But I can change the fact how I store the reference to the collection. And I want to understand what is the difference when I store the reference in the variable and in the Dictionary.

Comment: What component are we talking about here?

Comment: @HasBeanCounter, VirtualServerModeSource from devexpress